# How can I fix "1>LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, x86, visual-studio-2019

I know there are similar questions but mine is diffrent. I am trying to debugg a simple C++ program and have trouble debugging it. I use the latest VS 2019 community. I included following headers and files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

People said you need to copy paste files into 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin'
This dir doesnt exist. My directory is following: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VS. There I have 3 folders. Tools, Redist and Auxiliary.

Comment: your project is probably specifying a windows SDK version that doesn't exist

Comment: @AlanBirtles No. The Version in VS is 10.0 and the local Windows SDK is 10.0.19041.0. When I try the whole number it says it doesnt exist.

Comment: There should be a drop down menu with all the supported versions, choose one of those, if that's empty reinstall VS and make sure to select the option to install the windows SDK